# realtime audio processing possible?

Tags: sound, real-time

I'm an improvising musician and also a sound engineer. So, I'm interested in the creative process of music as well as the science of sound.

I would like to connect my guitar with an interface to my laptop and do all different kind of stuff with the incoming signal and send it back to an amplifier. So, is it possible to process audio in realtime with Mathematica?

Comment: Related or duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13656/realtime-audio-processing-using-dynamic and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2032/creating-a-realtime-midi-out and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47431/resources-for-sound-synthesis-design